# Proper way to declare log4j

Tags: log4j

I'd like to receive a clarification on the following:

Every class that has something to say in my program , creates its own logger like this

```
public final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class);
```

I was thinking ....

**Why is it public? Why is it customary to make it public?**

 - Logger is never reused from outside the class it was created

**Can there be a generic logger used throughout the program instead of having each class maintain its own?** 
 - Seems like ClassName is used as part of logging only to indicate WHAT class said what. Perhaps it is possible to pass a reference to the class name to the logger instead.

Please help me clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason to make it public is if you **want** it to be reused outside of the class.

You can have a single logger instance per you application, but you lose granularity of the messages available for configuring package or class level logging facilities.